# Different Impl of Serializer in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm using ASP.NET Core and I have an `ISerializer` interface that should provide different implementations of serializer, sometimes using Newtonsoft, and sometimes using `System.Test.Json`.

```
public interface IJsonSerializer
{
    string Serialize<TInput>(TInput input);

    TOutput Deserialize<TOutput>(string input);
};
```

The issue is related to setting, one of theme is using `JsonSerializerOptions`, and the other one is using `JsonSerializerSettings`.

How can I implement the interface base on two different types?

The implementations are in different projects that I'm using in an API later.

I tried to use a generic but it doesn't work.

I think it's not a good idea to create a **setting type** that contains both settings.

What is your suggestion?

Comment: Take a leaf out of MVC's design, `JsonOptions` vs `MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions`. Don't try to supply a generic interface, supply two methods to configure DI with the service implementation and options object.

Answer (score 0):

Consider something like this maybe:

```
public interface IJsonSettings
{

}

public interface IJsonSerializer<JsonSettings> where JsonSettings : IJsonSettings
{
    void ApplySettings(JsonSettings settings);

    string Serialize<TInput>(TInput input);

    TOutput Deserialize<TOutput>(string input);
}

public class NewtonSettings : IJsonSettings
{
    public JsonSerializerOptions Options;
}

// and then implement something like

public class NewtonSerializer : IJsonSerializer<NewtonSettings>
{
    private Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer;

    public void ApplySettings(NewtonSettings settings)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public TOutput Deserialize<TOutput>(string input)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public string Serialize<TInput>(TInput input)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The reasoning behind the empty interface, is to allow restriction of the generic used for the IJsonSerializer interface.